# Permutations of $(ab)x(ab)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

The problem states: Consider the following permutations:

$\alpha = (145)$, $\beta = (145)(3267)$

It then wants me to find the following permutations:

$(12)\alpha(12)$, $(12)\beta(12)$, $\alpha(12)\alpha^{-1}$, and $\beta(12)\beta^{-1}$

I am horrible at cycle notation, so I use the longer way to find disjoint cycles. An example of what I mean is this:

If I were to find the disjoint cycles of $(123)(23)$ I would do the following:

$(123)(23)$ = $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 &3\\2 & 3 &1\end{bmatrix}$  $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 &3\\1 & 3 & 2\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 &3\\2 & 1 &3\end{bmatrix}$ = $(12)(3)$

I was wondering if you could take a similiar approach to a problem like this. But I'm unsure how one would do so.

Like would: $(12)\alpha(12)$ = $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 &3&4&5\\2 & 1 &3&4&5\end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 &3&4&5\\4 & 2 &3&5&1\end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 &3&4&5\\2 & 1 &3&4&5\end{bmatrix}$ = $...$

Or am I just taking the wrong approach entirely?

Once I figure this out I can figure out a way to all $(ab)x(ab)$.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I guess your approach will work.  But if you just apply the permutations successively,  starting from the right, you get, for instance: $(12)\alpha (12)=(12)(145)(12)=(1)(245)=(245)$.  Be sure to account for where each of $1,\dots,5$ goes.

Comment: But I just did it and I got: $(12)\alpha(12)$ = $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 &3&4&5\\2 & 1 &3&4&5\end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 &3&4&5\\4 & 2 &3&5&1\end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 &3&4&5\\2 & 1 &3&4&5\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 &3&4&5\\4 & 1 &3&5&2\end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 &3&4&5\\2 & 4 &3&5&1\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 &3&4&5\\1 & 5 &3&2&4\end{bmatrix}$ = $(1)(254)(3)$ Where did I mess up?

Comment: I don't follow what you did.   The second equal sign...

Comment: Like you're unsure of what I did, or it just isn't correct?

Comment: I think it's incorrect.   You should "combine" the two on the right first.  But you have to go from right to left.

Comment: Wow, I know exactly what I did wrong.